# save check box to Boolean field in django using hand written form

Tags: python, django, forms, boolean

Hi trying to save checkbox value on submit. The form displays the value correct. When value is True is, its checked and when false its unchecked. However I just can't get it to save on POST.

views.py

> ```
>   @login_required(login_url='login') def engine(request):
>       eng= Player.objects.filter(customer=request.user.customer)    
>       isa= Customer.objects.filter(name=request.user.customer)
>    if request.method == "POST":
>       customer=request.user.customer
>     
>   isa =
>    Customer.objects.filter(name=request.user.customer)
>   .update(is_active=request.POST.get('is_active'))
>      isa.save()
>   return redirect('engine')   
>   
>      context= {'eng': eng, 'isa': isa}
>   return render(request, 'base/engine.html', context)
> ```

engine.html

> ```
>   {% csrf_token %}
>   {% for k in isa %}
>   
>   <label>ON/OFF</label> 
>       <input type="checkbox" id="is_active" name="is_active" {% if 
>    k.is_active == 1 %} checked{% endif %}>
>       <input type="submit" value="save" />
>   {% endfor %}
>   </form>
> ```

Comment: `Customer.objects.update(...)` This will update EVERY Customer object.  Is that what you really wanted?

Comment: ? I just want it update the single record is_active field.

Comment: If a checkbox isn't checked nothing is sent in the POST data, if it is checked the value sent by default is "on" so what you're really writing is either `.update(is_active=None)` or `.update(is_active="on")` I guess that should give you enough information to solve the problem? Note: It is better to use [form classes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/) with Django and let them handle all the cleaning / validation etc.